# Using System.Json for non-Silverlight projects?

Tags: c#, .net, json

Any idea on how to do it? If not possible, what's a good JSON library for C#?

Answer (score 15):

`System.Json` is now available in non-Silverlight projects via [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com) (.Net's package management system) and is hopefully going to be released as part of the core framework in vnext.  The NuGet package is named [JsonValue](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/JsonValue).

Imagine that we have the following JSON in the string variable `json`:

```
[{"a":"foo","b":"bar"},{"a":"another foo","b":"another bar"}]
```

We can get write the value "another bar" to the console using the following code:

```
using System.Json;
dynamic jsonObj = JsonValue.Parse(json);
var node = jsonObj[1].b;
System.Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
```

Comment: The `System.Json` package has been discontinued. You can find the appropriate classes in the framework itself.

Comment: The owner has unlisted this package :(

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Which version do you mean? The last nearly stable release was https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Json but now they have also deprecated it.

Comment: It's part of 4.6.2 now!

Comment: Also available as a Nuget package (with recent updates)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for JSON encoding/decoding, there is an official System.Web extension library from Microsoft that does it, odds are you probably already have this assembly (System.Web.Extensions):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

class App 
{
    static void Main(string[] args = null)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        String sJson = "{\"Name\": \"Your name\"}";
        DesJson json = jss.Deserialize<DesJson>(sJson);

        Console.WriteLine(json.Name);
    }
}

class DesJson {
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extenstion method to serialize any object instance to JSON:

```
public static class GenericExtensions
{
    public static string ToJsonString<T>(this T input)
    {
        string json;
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(input.GetType());
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ser.WriteObject(ms, input);
            json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
        return json;
    }
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web to use the DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Guthrie blogged about this

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use Mono's implementation of System.Json,
I was able to backport it to C# 2.0 with a few minor changes.

You can simply download my C# 2.0 project from [here](http://vm1.duckdns.org/Public/System.Json/System.Json.zip).