# Where do I get System.Json.dll for .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0

I am working on a .NET 4.0 Windows Service that references System.Json.dll. Where do I get that DLL from?

(No, I can't just upgrade to .NET 4.5.)

Comment: System.Json is a library for silverlight. See here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/670c7126-94cb-40b4-9dc5-744317e10c19

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using System.Json for non-Silverlight projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775692/using-system-json-for-non-silverlight-projects)